# 18.04 LTS - things look wrong

Tags: 18.04, video, youtube

I continue to be an idiot.

I have upgraded to 18.04 and it seems that sites such as youtube (in particular) are not functioning correctly.

On both the Firefox and Chromium browser, when one watches a video, it appears as it the right fifth of the video is underneath the sidebar, meaning that one cannot even full-screen the video to see it all as the icon is also unreachable.

This is a strange issue and I am stumped. I also don't know what the technical term for this would be.

Comment: This is most likely a browser problem and has nothing to do with the operating system. It's very interesting though because I'm also on 18.04 and I have no such problems. My YouTube works perfectly. So it must be something about your specific build that is causing this. Have you tried updating everything? Drivers, Browsers, Ubuntu Base, everything.

Comment: You may edit your question and add a screenshot. As we don't have this issue, it's difficult to know what you're talking about.

Comment: Try to start firefox with the `-P` flag from terminal (i.e. `firefox -P`) there create a fresh profile without deleting your existing one and try to start up firefox with the new profile and check if the problem persists.

Comment: One frequent cause of graphical issues in browsers is hardware acceleration, which can be turned off in Chromium advanced settings and in Firefox preferences (turn off recommended performance settings, then turn off hardware acceleration, then restart Firefox).